How to use `\let` with body-capturing inside `\NewDocumentEnvironment`?
As I update an old project to work with xparse, I am seeking to deploy \NewDocumentEnvironment in place of environ 's \NewEnviron and want to replicate the "body-capturing" functionality of the latter's \BODY command.  However I'm unsure of the equivalent to a command of the form
\let\foo\BODY
as one might have inside \NewEnviron : with the environment body in \NewDocumentEnvironment  referred to as (say) #1 instead of \BODY, then
\let\foo#1
certainly isn't equivalent to the former.  The closest I can manage to get is \def\foo{#1} , but this is sufficiently different that we get an error ("Illegal parameter number in definition of \Problem2 " ) with the following MWE, where the second problem environment happens to contain a command definition with parameters:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{probno}

\NewEnviron{problemold}{%
  \stepcounter{probno}%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname Problem\arabic{probno}\endcsname\BODY
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problemnew}{+b}{%
  \stepcounter{probno}%
  \global\expandafter\def\csname Problem\arabic{probno}\endcsname{#1}
}{}

\newcommand{\Problem}[1]{\csname Problem#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

%% "capture" (as global commands indexed by a counter) problems contributed by many authors:

\setcounter{probno}{0}

% prints using the call \Problem{1}
\begin{problemnew}
This is my first problem.
Does it show up in \textcolor{blue}{blue}?
\end{problemnew}

% prints using the call \Problem{2}
\begin{problemnew} % <--- this generates no error if "problemold" instead
This is my second problem.
\newcommand{\textcolorword}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}
Does it show up in in \textcolorword{green}?
\end{problemnew}

%% choose which problems to print, and in what order:

\Problem{2}

\medskip

\Problem{1}

\end{document}

This MWE is adapted from a "master" document that inputs files containing problems contributed by many authors; the master document captures each problem into a counter-indexed sequence of global commands (hence the use of \csname...\endcsname phrasing) and then outputs some selection of those exercises in a user-specified order.
I already know that two workarounds to this particular error are (1) tell the various problem authors that it's bad style to put command definitions into the middle of typeset math (and we already do this, moving their definitions to a macro file when we come across them), and/or (2) tell the problem authors to put an extra hash character in their command definitions (which is unintuitive for them, as they should be able to test their code separately before depositing it into our document tree).  But we on the editorial side don't want to interrupt the flow of the authors too much, and we want the pre-existing collection of old problems to still work without editing them too much more.  The goal is just to rewrite the master document to be more in line with xparse functionality rather than rely on packages like environ.
Is there a way to define an environment with \NewDocumentEnvironment that captures its body along the lines of \let in the problemold environment shown above?

The general low level trick to get macro parameters "escaped" automatically when doing assignments using \def is to either detour via a token register, or use the \unexpanded primitive introduced with e-TeX (which is basically doing the same on a lower level while being fully expandable).
The toks trick looks like the following:
\newtoks\tmptoks
...
\tmptoks={#1}
\edef\foo{\the\tmptoks}

However, since you're using LaTeX with xparse you're relying on e-TeX anyway, so the above is only educational. For your problem at hand (if you don't want to change much of your interface and make the switch to expl3, but rather have a minimal change), you can use:
\edef\foo{\unexpanded{#1}}

In your MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{probno}

\NewEnviron{problemold}{%
  \stepcounter{probno}%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname Problem\arabic{probno}\endcsname\BODY
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problemnew}{+b}{%
  \stepcounter{probno}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname Problem\arabic{probno}\endcsname{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}{}

\newcommand{\Problem}[1]{\csname Problem#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

%% "capture" (as global commands indexed by a counter) problems contributed by many authors:

\setcounter{probno}{0}

% prints using the call \Problem{1}
\begin{problemnew}
This is my first problem.
Does it show up in \textcolor{blue}{blue}?
\end{problemnew}

% prints using the call \Problem{2}
\begin{problemnew} % <--- this generates no error if "problemold" instead
This is my second problem.
\newcommand{\textcolorword}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}
Does it show up in in \textcolorword{green}?
\end{problemnew}

%% choose which problems to print, and in what order:

\Problem{2}

\medskip

\Problem{1}

\end{document}


Another possibility would be to use argument processors to be even more compatible to environ:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{probno}

\NewDocumentCommand\EnvironCompat{+m}
  {%
    \edef\BODY{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \let\ProcessedArg\BODY
  }

\NewEnviron{problemold}{%
  \stepcounter{probno}%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname Problem\arabic{probno}\endcsname\BODY
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problemnew}{>{\EnvironCompat}+b}{%
  \stepcounter{probno}%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname Problem\arabic{probno}\endcsname\BODY
}{}

\newcommand{\Problem}[1]{\csname Problem#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

%% "capture" (as global commands indexed by a counter) problems contributed by many authors:

\setcounter{probno}{0}

% prints using the call \Problem{1}
\begin{problemnew}
This is my first problem.
Does it show up in \textcolor{blue}{blue}?
\end{problemnew}

% prints using the call \Problem{2}
\begin{problemnew} % <--- this generates no error if "problemold" instead
This is my second problem.
\newcommand{\textcolorword}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}
Does it show up in in \textcolorword{green}?
\end{problemnew}

%% choose which problems to print, and in what order:

\Problem{2}

\medskip

\Problem{1}

\end{document}


Going down to expl3 is best, in such a case.
The idea is to store the text in a sequence so you don't need a counter, because you can use the position in the sequence.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_mathra_problem_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problemnew}{+b}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_mathra_problem_seq {#1}
 }{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Problem}{m}{\seq_item:Nn \g_mathra_problem_seq {#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%% "capture" (as global commands indexed by a counter) problems contributed by many authors:

% prints using the call \Problem{1}
\begin{problemnew}
This is my first problem.
Does it show up in \textcolor{blue}{blue}?
\end{problemnew}

% prints using the call \Problem{2}
\begin{problemnew}
This is my second problem.
\newcommand{\textcolorword}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}
Does it show up in in \textcolorword{green}?
\end{problemnew}

%% choose which problems to print, and in what order:

\Problem{2}

\medskip

\Problem{1}

\end{document}


However, I'd suggest a slightly different approach, namely of labeling the problems, so you don't need to rely on the order.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_mathra_problem_prop

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problemnew}{m+b}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_mathra_problem_prop {#1} {#2}
 }{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Problem}{m}{\prop_item:Nn \g_mathra_problem_prop {#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%% "capture" (as global commands indexed by a counter) problems contributed by many authors:

% prints using the call \Problem{1}
\begin{problemnew}{first}
This is my first problem.
Does it show up in \textcolor{blue}{blue}?
\end{problemnew}

% prints using the call \Problem{2}
\begin{problemnew}{second}
This is my second problem.
\newcommand{\textcolorword}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}
Does it show up in in \textcolorword{green}?
\end{problemnew}

%% choose which problems to print, and in what order:

\Problem{second}

\medskip

\Problem{first}

\end{document}

The output is the same as before.

Edited to avoid using multiple toks registers in light of this comment, for which I'd like to thank Ulrich Diez, except that I don't dare.
I'm not sure how to do this in LaTeX, as I believe they decided against providing an interface for this. But note that almost all beliefs I have in this domain are false.
You can avoid the need to double hashes in TeX by using toks rather than macros to store the problems. Since you are already eschewing the LaTeX layer fairly comprehensively in definitions, this might not be an issue.
For example,
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/733132/
% addaswyd o gwestiwn Mathra: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/733131/
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{probno}
\newtoks\tmptoks
\NewDocumentEnvironment{problemnew}{+b}{%
  \stepcounter{probno}%
  % sylwad Ulrich Diez: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/733131/how-to-use-let-with-body-capturing-inside-newdocumentenvironment/733132?noredirect=1#comment1826851_733132
  % sut i ddiolchi rywun, a gofynnodd i mi beidio â dweud wrtho fe, am sylwad? ????
  % dim on rhyfaint o registers tok felly well i ailddefnyddio'r un
  \tmptoks={#1}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname probtoks\arabic{probno}\endcsname{\the\tmptoks}%
  % \expandafter\newtoks\csname probtoks\arabic{probno}\endcsname
  % \expandafter\global\csname probtoks\arabic{probno}\endcsname{#1}%
}{}
\newcommand{\Problem}[1]{%
  % sylwad UD (gweler uchod): 'sdim angen \expandafter cyn \the am fod ‘expansion is not suppressed after \the’ ond wn i ddim sut ddeall y rhan 'ma - ro'n i'n meddwl bod \expandafter yn cwestiwn o _drefnu_ ... ????
  % \expandafter\the\csname probtoks#1\endcsname
  \csname probtoks#1\endcsname
}

\begin{document}

% prints using the call \Problem{1}
\begin{problemnew}
  This is my first problem.
  Does it show up in \textcolor{blue}{blue}?
\end{problemnew}

% prints using the call \Problem{2}
\begin{problemnew} % <--- this generates no error
  This is my second problem.
  \newcommand{\textcolorword}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}%
  Does it show up in in \textcolorword{green}?
\end{problemnew}

%% choose which problems to print, and in what order:

\Problem{2}

\medskip

\Problem{1}

\end{document}



I think the \newcommand line in problem 2 ought to have its ending commented, even though that isn't in the original. The spacing comes out wrong as-is. (but maybe that's just representative of authors' submissions ....)


The amount of \toks registers is limited, so probably better use a scratch-register and do \scratchtoks={#1}\expandafter\xdef\csname probtoks\arabic{probno}\endcsname{\the\scratchtoks}%  2. Expansion is not suppressed after \the, so \the\csname probtoks#1\endcsname instead of \expandafter\the\csname probtoks#1\endcsname would be sufficient.


As it seems you want to typeset problems, maybe you could try the xsim package. This package provides very flexible functionalities to collect and typeset exercises and solutions.
Define a custom exercise type
\DeclareExerciseType{problemnew}{
  exercise-env = problemnew,
  solution-env = solutionnew,
  exercise-name = problem,
  solution-name = solution,
  exercise-template = default,
  solution-template = default,
}

This will define two new environments problemnew and solutionnew (mandatory, even if not used).
If you don't want to typeset the problems when collected, set
\xsimsetup{
  problemnew/print = false,
  solutionnew/print = false,
}

Then you can print the problem you want with
\printexercise{problemnew}{2}

xsim provides many other functionalities, like defining collections, printing a random problem or customizing styles.
Note that because of
\newcommand{\textcolorword}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}

in the body you'll need the use-files option
\usepackage[use-files]{xsim}

This will create one temporary file per collected problem (you can hide them in a subfolder, if needed).
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[use-files]{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseType{problemnew}{
  exercise-env = problemnew,
  solution-env = solutionnew,
  exercise-name = problem,
  solution-name = solution,
  exercise-template = default,
  solution-template = default,
}

\xsimsetup{
  problemnew/print = false,
  solutionnew/print = false,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{problemnew}
  This is my first problem.
  Does it show up in \textcolor{blue}{blue}?
\end{problemnew}

\begin{problemnew}
  This is my second problem.
  \newcommand{\textcolorword}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}
  Does it show up in in \textcolorword{green}?
\end{problemnew}

\printexercise{problemnew}{2}

\printexercise{problemnew}{1}

\bigskip

There are \numberofproblemnews{} problems.
\end{document}


If you don't want titles, use
  exercise-template = minimal,
  solution-template = minimal,

